# IOS background location service, differ by time

Tags: ios, iphone, background, location

I am developing the IOS app with location server. In the app I am checking the user location periodically, and send the location details to the server.

Following are the steps:

1: App registers for location updates( in plist).

2: added the code like:

```
-(void)startUpdating{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //call web service location 
        [self UpdateAppmyLocation:@"1"];
    });
   [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:200 timeout:(NSTimeInterval)90];

}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

3: startUpdating method called in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Everything is working, but the didUpdateLocations:locations method called every minute. I am trying to add delay for some time so it will not lead to battery issue.

Note: Testing the app on iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: As per me allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled nowt working.

Comment: It is giving Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=11 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 11.) error.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://github.com/voyage11/Location
```

Use this code.you can set time after how much time you want to call it.
I have tried many codes, but i found this as most accurate and list battery issue.This is also awesome for background location service.

Comment: Location delegate will get fire whenever it gets the new location depending on setDesiredAccuracy and distanceFilter.......................................... you have to call [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; and [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; time to time whenever required.
 and

Comment: The application using timer and timer is not working in sleep mode. I want my app to go in sleep mode for 10-12 min. So it will reduce the battery power.

Comment: I have tested this code..It consumes very less battery power.. You can try this

Comment: Will it work in suspend mode? Also, what accuracy you are getting? Is apple accept your app?

Comment: No it wont work in suspend mode.. it will work in forground or background mode only